# Testing a URL provided from the server in a unit test

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, supertest

I'm using Mocha and supertest to do some simple testing in my NodeJS server. I now want to test this scenario:

1. Using my application in superset I make a request
2. The response contains a URL in it
3. I need to now test this URL is correct (via HTTP)

The URL will be the same server as running in superset. So if I first call `.get('/some-data')` the resulting URL will be fully qualified like `http://localhost:3456/a-path`.

I'm not clear how I could set this up, or if it is even possible using these tools.

Answer (score 0):

Yout could just require something like [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) or the like and them make a http-request and check if the status code is 200 etc.